# error pom.xml error resolving version and error packaging

Tags: spring, maven, pom.xml

I found the error in my pom.xml. the error below:

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>     - Error resolving version for plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin' from the repositories
>   [local (C:\Users\c76266.m2\repository), release.fusesource.org
>   (http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases),
>   ea.fusesource.org
>   (http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/ea), central
>   (https://      repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any
>   plugin repository
>     - Project build error: Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:2.3.7 or one of its dependencies
>   could not be resolved: The following       artifacts could not be
>   resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.7,
>   org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.7,
>   org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:
>      2.0.7, org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.7, org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.7,
>   org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.7,
>   org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-
>   default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1,
>   org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.7,
>   org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.0.7,
>   org.apache.maven:maven-    project:jar:2.0.7,
>   org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.7,
>   org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.7,
>   org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.0.7,
>   org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.7,
>   org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.0.7,
>   classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1: Could not transfer artifact
>   org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.7 from/to central
>   (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): unexpected end of stream on
>   Connection{repo.maven.apache.org:443,      proxy=HTTP @
>   idnproxy.pru.intranet.asia/10.171.74.5:8080 hostAddress=10.171.74.5
>   cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1} (recycle count=0)
>
> Project build error: Unknown packaging: bundle

[image: error pom.xml]

How to fix this problem? thanks.

Comment: The problem is located here: ` central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): unexpected end of stream on Connection{repo.maven.apache.org:443, proxy=HTTP @ idnproxy.pru.intranet.asia/10.171.74.5:8080 hostAddress=10.171.74.5 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1} (recycle count=0)` so looks like a proxy/firewall issue...furthermore it looks like you don't use a repository manager to handle accesses to central. etc.

Comment: if the problems from proxy, the library can't download and put to repository folder, is it true? because I success to download jar to repository folder with command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

The Maven xml include seems to be fine code wise, so I'd say you have imported/installed something wrong, a different version maybe?

Comment: if the problem from version, how to know the version is match with the others?

Answer (score 0):

this is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.prudential.integration.middleware.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>prudential-fuse-common-model</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>

    <name>Prudential Fuse Common Model</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>release.fusesource.org</id>
            <name>FuseSource Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>ea.fusesource.org</id>
            <name>FuseSource Community Early Access Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/ea</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>release.fusesource.org</id>
            <name>FuseSource Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>ea.fusesource.org</id>
            <name>FuseSource Community Early Access Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/ea</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.1.redhat-620133</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                    <groupId>asm</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4.redhat-620133</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jaxb</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.1.redhat-620133</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.7</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Name>${project.name}</Bundle-Name>
                        <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
                        <Import-Package>*</Import-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```